# At the time of, in the time of, in a time of

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Love *at the time of* Corona
>
> Love *in the time of* Corona
>
> Love *in a time of* Corona

Of the three expressions only
***[at the time of (something)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20the%20time%20of%20%28something%29)*** ( idiom) appears to be present in dictionaries, but I’ve come across all three forms.

Are all the above forms idiomatic and interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a take-off on the English translation of "El amor en los tiempos del colera" by G. García Márquez, which is usually translated into English as "Love in the Time of Cholera".
The version "in the time of" sounds like the best choice to me, the way that title is usually translated. "in a time of" isn't as good, since it's a unique time. "at the time of" sounds like a reference to clock time, rather than to an era.

Finally, you didn't ask about this, but "corona" might be better as "coronavirus" or "COVID-19", since "corona" might be referring to the name of the beer, or to a halo around the sun.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/columns/post/language-in-a-time-of-corona

Comment: *The box office factor caused the makers of 'Pearl Harbor' to have a love story against the backdrop of Japanese attack otherwise **there was not too much love at the time of World War II.*** https://books.google.it/books?id=HiA3X6RLLnYC&pg=PA194&dq=%22love+at+the+time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPoKKe0-vpAhWLyqQKHemMDhw4ChDoATADegQIARAZ#v=onepage&q=%22love%20at%20the%20time%22&f=false

Comment: @Gio Well, the other forms aren't impossible, just not the best choices, in my opinion.

Comment: 'At the time of' _usually_ means 'at the precise time when something else happened'. 'In the time of' is better when referring to a period of time.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent from the original question, but you can't really abbreviate Gabriel García Márquez's name in that way. His last name is "García Márquez" (or rather, the "García" is patronymic and the "Márquez" is matronymic), so you should not treat the "García" as if it's a given (middle) name.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Very good point. G. García Márquez. I think I'll fix it in the post.